# Determining the p-value of two consecutive residuals

Tags: regression, p-value, outliers, residuals

I am performing an outlier detection test in a monthly process to detect errors (for each month I have more or less 22 business days). I am using a Simple Linear Regression model.

What would be the p-value of having two stundetized residual consecutive with t-value 1,5 and -1,5?

I select the [Stundetized residuals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual) that are greater than 3 (the t-value) because I use the [Bonferroni Correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction).

I know that the distribution of the Stundetized residuals is a T-Student with n-k-2 freedom degree (in my model 22-1-2=19 freedom degree). According with the Bonferroni correction If I use a p-value of 5% I have to correct it with 5%/22 so I get a t-value greater than 3.5. I assume that if I use a t-value of 3 it is equivalent to a p-value of 15% more or less.

In the process that I am analyzing I discovered that sometimes when there is an error one day, I see the correction next day so I get a big Stundetized residual one day and I see another big Stundetized residual next day (with the opposite sign). What would be join p-value of getting two great Stundetized residuals in two consecutive days?

Comment: By "p-value" do you simply mean "probability" here? (Hypothesis tests are about parameters, not single values.)

Comment: Yes, I want to know what is the probability to obtain a stundetized residual of 1,5 (or grater) and next day a stundetized residual of -1.5 (or lower)